# How To Make a Generator, That's Composed of Another Generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, generator

I want to make a generator. And that generator should take an iterable. This is basically so that I can plug the generator into an existing framework.

This is the code I've got so far.

```
class Iter1(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.iterable is None:
            self.iterable = Iter2()
        return self.iterable

    def next(self):
        for thing in self.iterable:
            yield thing


class Iter2(object):

    DEFAULT_PATH = r"/Users/Documents/stuff.txt"

    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.path = path or self.DEFAULT_PATH

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    iterable = Iter1()
    for thing in iterable:
        print(thing)
```

There are two problems that I have with this code. The first is that what gets returned (yielded) isn't one of the lines from the file, it's another generator object. 
The second is that it doesn't return the number of lines that are in the file, it just returns an infinite number of lines. I get that that's because each time I call `next` in `Iter2` I'm opening the file again, but then I don't understand how to yield each line without loading the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 234 -- Iterators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/):

> Iterator objects returned by either form of iter() have a next()
>   method.  This method either returns the next value in the
>   iteration, or raises StopIteration (or a derived exception class)
>   to signal the end of the iteration.  Any other exception should be
>   considered to signify an error and should be propagated normally,
>   not taken to mean the end of the iteration.

You are returning an iterator from `next()`, which is why it's not working as expected. Instead you should return a single value each time `next()` is invoked.

Also, having `__iter__()` return `self` is a bit odd. It is generally assumed that invoking `iter(sequence)` multiple times will return multiple new iterators, each starting at the beginning of the sequence, but this isn't the case with your code.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but I don't quite understand where the problem is in my code. The `next` method in `iter2` should be yielding a line from the file, shouldn't it? Which should mean that the `next` method of `Iter1` is also yielding a single line, no?

Comment: @GreeTreePython No, using `yield` inside `next()` is just not right. In this case, your iterator wrapper could do something like this: `def next(self): return next(self.iterator)`. Python itself will call your `next()` method repeatedly, and it will return one value each time, or throw a `StopException` when there's no more. Since the iterator you're wrapping has the same `next` behavior, you can just forward it directly.